# Trying to copy/paste image from RichTextBlock

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml

How can I copy/paste in RichTextBlock (a image)? Properties exist in a RichTextBlock for copy/paste?

Here is an example of what I'm creating:

```
<RichTextBlock x:Name="txbTermsConditions" Height="Auto" Width="319" FontSize="16">
             <Paragraph>
                 //Example of xaml... the image is from file.xml
            </Paragraph> 
</RichTextBlock>
```

If I select all of the text or image from this piece of Xaml and copy/paste it in NotePad, I cant select the text or image to copy/paste.

Comment: could you plz explain more what y need

Comment: I need to copy/paste the image and text the RichTextBlock present. To the NotePad for example.

Comment: Right now i cant copy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this code

```
      private void richTextBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
                {   //click event
                    //MessageBox.Show("you got it!");
                    ContextMenu contextMenu = new System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu();
                    MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem("Cut");
                    menuItem.Click += new EventHandler(CutAction);
                    contextMenu.MenuItems.Add(menuItem);
                    menuItem = new MenuItem("Copy");
                    menuItem.Click += new EventHandler(CopyAction);
                    contextMenu.MenuItems.Add(menuItem);
                    menuItem = new MenuItem("Paste");
                    menuItem.Click += new EventHandler(PasteAction);
                    contextMenu.MenuItems.Add(menuItem);

                    richTextBox1.ContextMenu = contextMenu;
                }
            }
            void CutAction(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                richTextBox1.Cut();
            }

            void CopyAction(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Graphics objGraphics;
                Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Rtf, richTextBox1.SelectedRtf);
                Clipboard.Clear();
            }

            void PasteAction(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (Clipboard.ContainsText(TextDataFormat.Rtf))
                {
                    richTextBox1.SelectedRtf
                        = Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Rtf).ToString();
                }
            }
```

f you want to copy paste with another application like notepad (text only not the styles) please replace following methods

```
void CopyAction(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Clipboard.SetText(richTextBox1.SelectedText);
        }

        void PasteAction(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Clipboard.ContainsText())
            {
                richTextBox1.Text
                    += Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Text).ToString();
            }
        }
```

Comment: I dont have 8.1 I'm in 8.0

Comment: what's the prb with 8.1 and 8.0